# Oracle : How to get the sum & count based on minimum date value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have table as following :

Table 1  ( Column1,column2,column3,date)

I want to get count(column 1) & sum(column2) and the same count / sum when date is greater than the minimum date value in date column.

Although the 4 required value can be controlled by one condition on column 3.

```
Column 1 , Column 2 , Column 3 , Date
A           1           1           5/5/2016
G           5           0           5/10/2016
B           1           2           5/10/2016
A           12          1           5/10/2016
D           1           1           5/5/2016
A           1           1           5/11/2016
C           7           1           5/5/2016
C           1           1           5/12/2016
E           10          2           5/10/2016
```

I want when filter on column 3 = 1 get the following result :

```
Count (1) , Sum(2) , Count(1) when date greater than minimum ,Count(2) when date greater than minimum
3         , 23     ,   2                                     , 14
```

I tried to use case put I don't need to group by values.

how can I generate query fulfill above requirements in oracle

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`.  As you describe:

```
select count(column1), sum(column2),
       count(case when date > mindate then column1 end),
       sum(case when date > mindate then column2 end)
from (select t.*, min(date) over () as mindate
      from table1 t
     ) t;
```

This uses a window function to get the minimum date, which is used in the `case`.

Comment: thanks for your appreciated help , If i need to put condition overall for column  3 I should but it twice ? one to inside date select and one inside overall selection ?

Comment: Also this get minimum overall column not on column 3 condition

Comment: @AhmedEmad . . . I understand your question to be:  "I want to get count(column 1) & sum(column2) and the same count / sum when date is greater than the minimum date value in date column."  If you have another question, ask it as *another* question and not in a comment.

Comment: this is part of above question as i mentioned above in my question : "Although the 4 required value can be controlled by one condition on column 3." , "I want when filter on column 3 = 1 get the following result ".However I solved it by adding PARTITION by in over condition.